# How to store radio button value in Database?

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page, on which I have radio button giving a choice of male or female.

When I click on a radio button then that particular entry is not get submitted in my database.

How should I store that value in database?

Comment: You should give more information: what have you tried, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?  If there was an error message, what was it? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is overly broad. There are so many things which needs to happen between "click on a radio button" and "submitted in database". You are not specific about which step exactly fails. It would be nice if you put in some effort by yourself to naildown the exact step which fails. This way we can faster provide a well-suited answer. You can use Firebug or Fiddler2 to track HTTP requests/responses. You can use the IDE-builtin debugger to track the code execution of Java code step by step and all variables currently in scope/memory. You can use a logger in Java side and/or a SQL monitor in DB side to track the SQL queries.

---

Anyway, here's a kickoff example of how things are supposed to happen in its most simplest form so that you can compare it with your setup and naildown the issue.

1. Have a nullable `gender` column in your `User` table which accepts the set of values `M` or `F` (which stands for male or female).
2. Have a form in your JSP which allows the user to select it.

   ```
   <form action="servleturl" method="post">
       ...
       <br />
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" /> Male
       <br />
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" /> Female
       <br />
       <input type="submit" />
   </form>
   ```
3. Have a servlet which listens on `/servleturl` and gathers the submitted value in `doPost()`.

   ```
   // ...
   String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
   // ...
   ```
4. Have a DAO class which does the following:

   ```
   // ...
   preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO User (col1, col2, col3, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
   // ...
   preparedStatement.setString(4, gender);
   // ...
   preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
   // ...
   ```